# How to get the year where the max and min value occurs in pandas

Tags: python-3.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqa6X.png)

Please take a look at the picture for `df`

I have this set of data-frame. I found the mean, max, and min value that occurred from 2008-2012 using:

```
mean=(df.iloc[1:6,1].mean())
print(f"Mean for dividends from 2008-2012 is {mean}")
column=(df.iloc[1:6,1])
max_value=column.max()
min_value=column.min()
```

How am I supposed to get the year where the max and min occurred from 2008-2012?

Answer (score 0):

You can get row number using argmin and argmax

```
min_value_row = column.argmin()
max_value_row = column.argmax()
```

Then you can use it to get date (expecting 0 column is the date):

```
date_min = df.iloc[column.argmin(),0]
date_max = df.iloc[column.argmax(),0]
```

In your case:

```
column_dividends_selected = df.Dividends.iloc[1:6]

min_value = column_dividends_selected.min()
max_value = column_dividends_selected.max()

min_value_row = column_dividends_selected.argmin()
max_value_row = column_dividends_selected.argmax()


column_date_selected = df.Year.iloc[1:6]

date_min = column_date_selected.iloc[min_value_row]
date_max = column_date_selected.iloc[max_value_row]
```